# Using Weka NaiveBayes with Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka

I created a NaiveBayes model in Weka. I exported the model to disk. I now want to inject this model into MATLAB 2018, so that I can check how it performs via some data that I am receiving.

I load my model in MATLAB, by stating something like this:

```
loadedModel = weka.core.SerializationHelper.read('myweka.model');
```

I then create a Weka Instance object, and let it contain this data:

```
instance = infrequent,low,high,medium-high,high,medium,medium,low,low
```

If I run these two commands:

```
loadedModel.distributionForInstance(instance)
loadedModel.classifyInstance(instance)
```

I see the following output:

```
0.0001
0.9999
1
```

This is odd to me because if I observe the same record in WEKA ui, I see the same instance with probabilities 0.993 and 0.007, classified as '2'. (I can load the same model multiple times from disk in WEKA, and reproduce this behavior, which is correct) After further investigation, I noticed that regardless of the sequence of attributes my Instance object has, I always get the same probability output and the same classification by invoking the model via MATLAB.

There are some posts on the net that share the same problem, like these:

[Always getting the same output](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Always-getting-the-same-output-for-text-classification-no-matter-the-input-td42169.html)

[Weka - Classifier returns the same distribution for any input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830946/weka-classifier-returns-the-same-distribution-for-any-input)

However, the recommended solution to call 'instance.setClassMissing()' did not solve my issue. Is there anything I am missing, or can try to do in order to further troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does your test instance has same structure as your train set? If not, you need yo provide the same structure.

Weka indexes nominal attributes and stores the indices internally. So the nominal attributes order in train file is important. For example if your attribute is mapped as low=>0, high=>1 in training, you need to map them like this in your test set. Usually this is achieved by serializing the train header with the model.

Sample code for creating train header:

```
Instances trainHeader = new Instances(instances, 0);
trainHeader.setClassIndex(instances.classIndex());
```

When creating a new instance set its dataset:

```
Instance instance = ...
instance.setDataset(trainHeader);
```